# Django template: How to use values/values_list

Tags: django, django-templates

In template I am trying to do something like this:

```
{{ request.user.profile.following.all.values_list }}
```

and I get

> <QuerySet [(7, 2, 1)]>

, but I want to get

> <QuerySet [2]>

like in Django values_list.
For example: `Follow.objects.filter(follow_by=self.request.user.profile).values_list('follow_to', flat=True)`
Can I pass argument like this in template?

Comment: Django deliberately restricts its template language *not* to perform subscripting or function calls to methods with parameters. This is *business logic* and belongs in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I pass argument like this in template?

**No**. The Django template engine *deliberately* restricts this, since this is logic that belongs in the *view*. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    following = request.user.profile.following.values_list('follow_to', flat=True)
    return render(
        request,
        'some_template.html',
        {'following': following}
    )
```

You can then render this with:

```
{{ following }}
```

That being said, using [**`.values_list(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) is often an anti-pattern, since it erodes the model layer. It is thus something related to the [*primitive obsession* antipattern [refactoring.guru]](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession).